Is a specific date of occurrence required for a felony charge?

Can a person be charged for a felony in the state of Missouri without a specific date ever being stated that the crime occurred?
Example:
"Defendant committed a felony between the dates of Jan 1 2023 and Dec 31 2023 by beating the victim and causing serious bodily injury."

How can a defendant properly provide a defense if there is no specific date given that the crime occurred?

What would be legal arguments to dismiss such vague charges?



A course of conduct crime, for example sexual abuse of a child on multiple occasions over a period of time, is ordinarily charged with a starting and ending date, not one particular date.

Fun (?) fact: French indictments used to have the formulation "committed in place X at time Y, or at a place within French jurisdiction and at a time within the statute of limitations". Prosecutors probably thought it was a smart way to go around specificity requirements. Nope, said the Cour de Cassation this April: X and Y are in fact binding on what the court can rule on. Hopefully this bit of legalese will fall away.

As they say on TV procedural shows, "on or about the time of...".  If your credit card goes missing, and I am caught trying to use it, it is not necessary to prove exactly when it was removed from my wallet. It may be necessary to establish a rough date to show that statute of limitations has not expired, or to demonstrate to a jury how this may have happened; more precision maybe needed to overcome an alibi. But, at least in the us, the criterion for conviction is that the jury believes the defendant was guilty beyond a reasonable doubt based upon the preponderance of evidence.

Imagine if a specific date was required - it would always be a good idea to commit crimes near the stroke of midnight, allowing you to walk free after the prosecution finds themselves unable to determine the exact date of the crime. This, of course, does not work.

The answers to 2 and 3 depend on the prosecution's case.  In any event, the defendant isn't required to present an alibi.  The prosecutor has to present evidence showing that the defendant committed the crime; the specific strategies for rebutting the evidence depend on what the evidence is.

@UJM If I understand correctly, this case is about a former employee complaining about his past employer kept doing a background check on them after they were no longer employed, from 2009 to 2012, but could only demonstrate that an access to personal data took place in 2003. In this case I'm not surprised the court of appeal reverted the judgement, the requirement for a crime to take place within a three-year period doesn't seem abusive.

@keshlam in France, art. 388 CPP requires that the judge only has jurisdiction over what the indictment says. It does not need to be an exact date ("you stole from the cookie jar between Monday and Thursday" is OK) but it needs to be sufficiently precise to allow the defense to prepare for trial ("you did some crime at some point in time" is not OK). See also ECHR 6.3(a).

@DmitryGrigoryev your timeline is right, but it was not a statute of limitations issue (the timer starts when facts are discovered rather than when they happen for some infractions, which was the case here). Also, this was not really a "background check". US-style background checks are done (1) on prospective rather than current employees, (2) with the person’s knowledge, (3) in a systematic manner ("all candidates" or "all candidates to such-and-such position"). None of those applied here. (Also, background checks are not widely practiced in France.)

A totally innocent person may or may not have an alibi for the time of the crime, that is just luck. If I’m accused of burglary sometime in the last 14 days, it’s very unlikely that I have an alibi for the whole time, and a guilty person might have alibis for 12 of 14 days. Would/ should that be taken into account?

Assume that Olivia Owner returns to her holiday cottage after some months in the city. She finds it burgled and files a report. Through invoices and serial numbers, she can provide credible evidence that she owns certain items.
Some time later Barry Burglar is caught breaking into a different house. A search of Barry's house turns up a computer with the serial number from Olivia's report hidden in a closet.
So can Barry be charged with breaking into Olivia's cottage, even if nobody can say with any certainty when it happened? Probably. Barry could say that the prosecution did not prove their case because the charge is so vague, and hope for the jury to accept that. Or Barry could claim that he purchased the computer at a garage sale some weeks ago. The success of such a defense may get more likely if the prosecution cannot pin the date of the supposed burglary down and there are large gaps in the timeline.

It sounds like the prosecution's problem is proving that he actually committed the burglary, and the lack of a specific date is an almost negligible component of that.

@Barmar I wouldn't call it almost negligible as the prosecution not having a specific date will be broadly used by the defence to sow doubt in the jury

@Hobbamok, depends very much on the details. In my example, the suspected thief had stolen goods. A few years after the theft, it should be plausible to argue that "it was from a garage sale, two or three years ago, I don't remember the details." A few weeks after the theft, less so.

@o.m.: I would tend to expect, in this example, for the defense to argue that the prosecution has failed to introduce evidence supporting all elements of the crime, and that Barry should have been charged with possession of stolen property or something along those lines instead of theft and/or burglary. The defense would likely also argue that, under the prosecutor's theory, any case in which there is evidence of possession would also be a case in which there is evidence of theft, effectively nullifying the requirement to prove all elements of the crime.

If Barry's fingerprints or DNA are found on the broken window lock in Olivia's cottage even though Barry claims never to have visited that location, then combined with Barry holding Olivia's reported missing property, the evidence may be more than sufficient to persuade a jury without a fixed date.

That's not a very good example. The case seems very flimsy. Handling or receipt of stolen property is typically a separate offense.

@Relaxed, receipt of stolen property would require knowledge, which gets easier to deny the longer the timeline gets. I wonder if a fingerprint on a window would help or confuse the example.

@Relaxed: Having a separate offense for the acquisition of property in a manner which is wantonly indifferent to whether it was stolen accommodates situations where one can prove that a defendant was at best wantonly indifferent to the origin of property that happens to have been stolen.  Such a charge might be applicable if e.g. an accused thief plausibly claims to have bought what would normally be a $5,000 television for $50 from a guy selling it from the back of his van.  If someone found with stolen property can't offer any explanation for either how he acquired it, or...

...how it could have entered his possession without his knowledge (e.g. the property was found in a storage locker with a broken lock, which the locker's owner claims to have visited only infrequently) however, the implication would be that the person was involved with or had actual knowledge of the theft.



Can a person be charged for a felony in the state of Missouri without a specific date ever being stated that the crime occurred.


Yes. Some time frame is necessary, but it need not be a specific date. For example, many murders that take place in remote places can be narrowed down to some time frame, but not a specific date. The answer from o.m. gives another good example.


How can a defendant properly provide a defense if there is no specific
date given that the crime occurred.


The same way that a defendant would in any other case.


What would be legal means to dismiss such vague charges?


A legally insufficient indictment can be challenged in a pre-trial motion filed by the defense. The question doesn't identify a ground for a legally insufficient indictment, but a small percentage of indictments are dismissed every year on the grounds that they are legally insufficicent.
